# How to set a number of decimals in string.Join?

Tags: c#

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{name} -> {string.Join(" ", b[name]):F2} (avg: {b[name].Average():F2})");
```

I am not exactly sure how to use `:F2` in `string.Join`, since it isn't working. Can you tell me how exactly to use it?

Comment: What is `b` and `name`?

Comment: We don't know what `b[name]` is, or what you expect the result to be. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `b`s indexer returns some collection of numbers - you need to provide correct format before joining numbers into string. You can use `ToString` overload that accepts [the number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f):  `string.Join(" ", b[name].Select(n => n.ToString("F2")))` resulting in something like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{name} -> {string.Join(" ", b[name].Select(n => n.ToString("F2")))} (avg: {b[name].Average():F2})");
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that `b[name]` actually returns a *collection* of numbers. Otherwise there's nothing to join, and nothing to take an average of. But without a [mcve] we're really just guessing :(

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you, was fixing the answer.